# New line after 12 chars java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have a class which can read a file, modify it an write it to another file. The characters in the output are correct , the only problem is that the lines need to have a length of 12 chars.
How can I achieve this with my existing code?(I wrote a comment where in the code I want to do this)

```
My input file: http://gyazo.com/13fe791d24ef86e29ab6a6e89d0af609
The current output: http://gyazo.com/cc195c1d59a9d1fe3b4f2c54e71da8eb
The output I want : http://gyazo.com/04efcbb05c5d56b6e28972feb8c43fb8


String line;
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

public void readFile(){

    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/Sybren/Desktop/Invoertestbestand1.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));


        //String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            //buf.append(line);
            processInput();
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
    }
}
public void processInput(){

    buf.append(line);  

    if (buf.length()>7){
        buf.append("-");
    }


    /* if a * is followed by * change them to a !  */
    for (int index = 0; index < buf.length(); index++) {
        if (buf.charAt(index) == '*' && buf.charAt(index+1) == '*') {
            buf.setCharAt(index, '!');
            buf.deleteCharAt(index+1);
        }     

    } 
    // get last character from stringbuilder and delete      
    buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length()-1);

    /* start with a new line if the line length is bigger than 12 - how to do it? */
    //???

}


public void writeFile() {
    try {

        String content = buf.toString();

        File file = new File("C:/Users/Sybren/Desktop/uitvoer1.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Print a newline after every twelve characters.

Answer (score 0):

Would something along these lines help?

```
for (int i=13;i<buf.size();i+=13) {
  buf.insert(i, '\n');
  i++; // to account for the newline char just added
}
```

The numbers used may not be correct, either because of misunderstanding of the question or because it isn't tested.

Comment: The code doesn't work it does nothing with my output

Comment: The answer adds newlines into the "buf" StringBuilder. The code in the question does nothing with "buf", and processInput() does not return anything. Your output only seems to print out the input, so the answer verbatim will have no effect.

Comment: My input is changed by processInput() so the output doesn't print out the input. All other lines in processInput() are executed except the lines you suggested.

Comment: buf is the variable which the edits are being made to. buf is never printed out, nor is line set to its contents. You print out line before processInput() is called, so even if line were to be updated - you wouldn't see it in the output. writeFile() is never called. If I have misunderstood your question, then I am sorry, but in this case a re-word and reduced code example would help.

Comment: Content contains buf.toString and writeFile() is called in the main.You're right that I print the input first but I also change it and write it to another file.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int index = 0; index < buf.length(); index++) {
        if (buf.charAt(index) == '*' && buf.charAt(index+1) == '*') {
            buf.setCharAt(index, '!');
            buf.deleteCharAt(index+1);
        }    
}
```

There will be an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at the end of the loop when you you call index+1

Comment: I don't get exceptions because it looks for two * and replaces the first one with a ! and deletes the second one.